# Convert character varying(255)[] to JSONB

Tags: postgresql

I currently have array of strings `character varying(255)[]` and want to convert it to a `JSONB` object. When I try to cast it directly, it results in an error, despite it being a valid JSON, is there a nice way to convert it?:

`ERROR:  cannot cast type character varying[] to jsonb`

Answer (score 3):

You can not convert the array of strings to the single JSON object (directly at least). If you need to convert it to the array of JSONs use

```
select yourvalue::jsonb[];
```

If you need to convert it to the JSON array use

```
select jsonb_agg(unnest::jsonb) from unnest(yourvalue);
```

or

```
select to_jsonb(yourvalue::jsonb[]);
```

where `yourvalue::jsonb[]` ensures that all values in the array is really valid JSON and `to_jsonb(...)` converts it to the JSONB array.

Example:

```
with t(x) as (values(array['["a","b","c"]','{"d":"e"}','1']))
select to_jsonb(x::jsonb[]) from t;
```

Output:

```
[["a", "b", "c"], {"d": "e"}, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole collection of possibilities, depending on what's your exact need, and what's the exact format of your `character varying[]` columns:

1. `cast` to `json[]` (or to `jsonb[]`)

   ```
   WITH t(cv_arr) AS
   (
       VALUES (ARRAY['"a"', '"b"', '"c"']::character varying[])
   )
   SELECT 
       cv_arr::json[] 
   FROM   t ;
   -- Returns [a,b,c] of type json[]

   WITH t(cv_arr) AS
   (
       VALUES (ARRAY['"a"', '"b":2', '"c"']::character varying[])
   )
   SELECT 
       cv_arr::json[] 
   FROM   t ;
   -- Errors out
   -- ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
   -- DETAIL:  Expected end of input, but found ":".
   -- CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: "b":...
   ```
2. `to_json` function

   ```
   WITH t(cv_arr) AS
   (
       VALUES (ARRAY['a', '"b":2', 'c']::character varying[])
   )
   SELECT 
       to_json(cv_arr)
   FROM t ;
   -- Returns [a,"b":2,c] of type json
   ```
3. `array_to_json` function

   ```
   WITH t(cv_arr) AS
   (
       VALUES (ARRAY['a', '"b":2', 'c']::character varying[])
   )
   SELECT 
       array_to_json(cv_arr)
   FROM t ;
   -- Returns [a,"b":2,c] of type json
   ```
4. `json_build_array` function

   ```
   WITH t(cv_arr) AS
   (
       VALUES (ARRAY['a', '"b":2', 'c']::character varying[])
   )
   SELECT 
       jsonb_build_array(cv_arr)
   FROM t ;
   -- Returns [["a","\"b\":2","c"]]  of type jsonb
   ```
5. `unnest` and `json_agg`

   ```
   WITH t(cv_arr) AS
   (
       VALUES (ARRAY['a', '"b":2', 'c']::character varying[])
   )
   SELECT 
       json_agg(x)
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT unnest(cv_arr) AS x
       FROM t 
   ) AS s0 ;
   -- Returns [a,"b":2,c] of type json
   ```

These functions are all available for PostgreSQL >= 9.5 and some of them were already available for 9.4. You can check the [JSON functions documentation about PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) for specific details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_to_json` function. Here is the proof;

```
--generates character varying[] for testing
WITH varchar_array AS 
(
  SELECT array_agg(a::VARCHAR (255)) AS va
  FROM generate_series(1, 10) a
) 

--usage
SELECT array_to_json(va)::JSONB FROM varchar_array

--Result:
--["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

You can remove `::JSONB` part if you don't need jsonb type for your output.

For additional json functions you can check documentation sections;

- [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)
- [General-Purpose Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) ( for json aggregate functions)